# Execute command line order from Coffee-script

Tags: command-line, coffeescript

is it possible to execute a command line order such as 'll', 'pwd' or whatever from a Coffee script?

I've tried to find examples without luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you execute CoffeeScript via Node.js you will have full access to the abilities of your OS. Use the `spawn` method of the [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) module to create a new process:

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'
ls = spawn 'ls', ['array', 'of', 'options']
# receive all output and process
ls.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString().trim()
# receive error messages and process
ls.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString().trim()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but isn't it the same to do `spawn 'ls', ['array', 'of', 'options'], stdio: 'inherit'` instead of adding those other two lines for IO redirection?

Comment: I dont think so. It seems to me that giving a hash with the key stdio will reroute the io stream to another io stream then to the default one.

Comment: I've been using that method and basically what it does is use the current `process` streams for the new spawned process. But well, idk if there are any difference with printing stdout and stderr manually.

Comment: Thanks! just needed to replace a "." with a "," was: `ls.stderr.on 'data'. (data) -> console.log data.toString().trim()` fixed: `ls.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString().trim()`